# What rewards do you get for playing an Ultimate Team game in Madden 12?

Tags: madden-12

I'm not great at Madden (I play on All-Pro with decent teams, struggle against humans but can beat the CPU pretty regularly), and even with the returning-veteran bonus I got from playing MUT in Madden 10, I don't have a lot of coins.

I'm trying to save up for a decent pack (to boost my team enough that I don't have to play the Cardinals every game), so I'm curious to know what my best options are in CPU play with respect to difficulty level and quarter length. Obviously a longer game gives me more time to rack up offensive stats, but that allows the AI to take away my defensive stats ... but what exactly do those stats give me, and what should I be trying to do in-game to maximize my return?